# How to make a function that calculates newtons quotient for f(x) = exp(x) in R?

Tags: r, math

I'm working on an assignment for class and I'm a little lost with trying to write a function out which will calculate Newton's quotient.
This is what the questions is asking

The derivative of a function `f(x)` can be approximated by the Newton's quotient `(f(x+h) - f(x))/h`

where `h` is a small number.  Write a function to calculate the Newton's quotient
for `f(x) = exp(x)`.  The function should take two scalar arguments, `x` and `h`.
Use a default value of `h=1e-6`.
Test your function at the point `x=1` using the default value of `h`, and compare
to the true value of the derivative `f'(1) = e^1`.

So far I have written the code as so

```
x=1
newton = function(x, h = 1e-06){
   quotiant = ((x+h) - x)/h

   return(x = exp(x))
}

y = newton(1,h)
print(y)
```

I can see this is wrong, but I don't really understand how I can fix this, and what exactly I'm trying to calculate.

I have also tried this code

```
x=1
newton = function(x, h = 1e-06){
   quotiant = ((x+h) - x)/h


}

y = newton(1,h)
print(y)
```

which I think gives me the right answer, but again I don't really understand what I'm calculating.

Answer (score 2):

Your function doesn't evaluate the values of x and x+h using the exponential function. In your two examples you are either just returning the exponential of x, or not using the exponential function at all. What you want is something like this:

```
newton = function(x, h = 1e-06){
   quotient = (exp(x+h) - exp(x))/h
   quotient
}
newton(1)
```

Comment: of course... that makes so much sense now. I was confused where to incorporate the f(x)... but the f is the function, which is exp.